# Jest: Cannot set property 'props' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm starting learning Jest and I created this test. But when I run it, I receive this message below.

Am I passing the props to the AppComponent the wrong way?

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'props' of undefined

App.js:

```
const { store } = this.props;

return (
  <div>
    <h2 className={css(styles.hover)}>Welcome to the { store.name } project!</h2>
    <h3>This project is { store.description }.</h3>
    <MyComponent store={store} />
  </div>
);
```

App-test.js:

```
const storeProp = {
  name: 'Reaxor',
  description: 'Hello'
}

describe('App', () => {
  it('returns the correct text', () => {

    // Render a checkbox with label in the document
    const app = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      <App store={storeProp} />
    );

    const appNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(app);

    const h2 = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(app, 'h2')
    const h3 = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(app, 'h3')

    expect(h2.textContent).toEqual('Welcome to the Reaxor project!');
    expect(h3.textContent).toEqual('This project is Hello.')
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like something is mocked that shouldn't be mocked. You could try disabling automocking `"automock": false` in the config and see if that model works better for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I cannot add comments yet, but I'd like to comment: A line number would help (or even better, a stack trace). Is it

```
const app = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
    <App store={storeProp} />
);
```

that's throwing the error?

You also need to give more context around App.js.

React internally creates a 'props' argument that is an object, and sticks the props onto it as arguments. It's trying to do that onto something that is undefined. That would suggest that something is wrong with how you're getting to `<App />`.

- Are you requiring App.js in your test file?
- Are you making sure jest isn't mocking it? (it does this by default in some versions, for all required files.)
- Is App.js written correctly (I hope there's a lot more in that file than you're showing us...)?
- Are you exporting from App.js correctly (this seems a good candidate for this error message)?

As for your **actual** question, no, you are not passing in the props incorrectly. That part of the syntax is correct.

Comment: This is the App.js: http://pastebin.com/dyrN2bZZ
And this is the test file: http://pastebin.com/D45BfMmn

The error:  at App (src/components/App/App.js:10:245)

I believe that the test is not passing the props correctly, so this.props is undefined.

Comment: it's not saying `this.props` is undefined, it's saying `this` (or whatever props is attempting to be assigned to internally while it does its magic to give access to this.props) is undefined.

You're using some fancy ES6 features for importing that I haven't used much, so I'd check those a little more closely.

But you're definitely passing in props correctly. I do the same in my jest files. Here's an example of how I'm using these features: http://imgur.com/1UthIlb

Answer (score 0):

Is it the full version of App.js?
You should use the class notation to use this.props.
If you use the function notation, just props.